# Walk through folders until specific ending number python

Tags: python

I have a range of folders which are named like folder0, folder2,..., folder99. Now I want to walk through folder0,..., folderX and print their files. X should stay variable and easy to change.

My code looks something like this but its not working how I want it to work yet because I can't decide until which number I want to go.

```
import os
import re

rootdir = r'path'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for dir in dirs:
        if not re.match(r'folder[0-9]+$', dir):
            dirs.remove(dir)
    for file in files:
        print files
```

Comment: Remove `folder` from name, change rest into `int` and compare with `X`

Comment: how would that look like? change rest into `int`?

Comment: `folder25` (string) -> `25` (string) -> `a = int('25')` (integer) -> `if a < X:`

Comment: I cant get rid of the folder names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your name scheme is consistent, which you state, why do the os.walk?

```
import os

dir_path = '/path/to/folders/folder{}'

x = 10

for i in range(0, x):
    formatted_path = dir_path.format(i)
    try:
        for f in os.listdir(formatted_path):
            filename = os.path.join(formatted_path, f)
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                print filename

    except OSError:
        print "{} does not exist".format(formatted_path)
```